# Defining a set of axes.

Tags: coordinate-systems, vector-analysis

I was reading up a little on reference frames and am confused about a certain detail. Is it correct to say that the positive $x$-axis, for example, can be defined as follows?

$$
X^+ = \lim_{C \rightarrow \, 0^+} C^{-1}\langle 1,0,0\rangle  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (1)
$$

Here, $\langle a_1, a_2, a_3\rangle$ represents the vector with origin at $(0,0,0)$ and terminal point at $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$. Also, this is just a question *I* have, not something I read. Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: There was an error concerning $C$. I've fixed that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it wouldn't be correct to say that. Firstly, the limit of a sequence of vectors is just another vector (if it exists); and secondly, that sequence of vectors has no limit. Also, I'd say that an axis consists of points, not vectors.

So a  correct alternative would be: the set
 $$\{(a_1,0,0)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid a_1>0\}$$
forms the positive $x$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^3$. You could also use
$$\displaystyle\bigcup_{C>0}\{C(1,0,0)\}.$$

Comment: Oh, yeah! I knew I was missing something. Thanks!

Comment: And, btw, really nice set of quotes on your site.

Comment: Thank you, I enjoy rereading them often :)